# Ubuntu boot error possibly drive

Tags: boot, drive

Hello I try to install ubuntu from DVD, I set booting from dvd in bios but I see some errors like failed command: `IDENTIFY PACKET DEVICE or failed command READ FPDMA QUEUED`, it looks like hard drive error but im not an expert in this, thats why i ask. Here are photos of whole screen.

[image]

My drive is Seagate Barracuda 500GB SATA3 if its matters

Comment: Yes, most likely a failed drive. But also check whether or not the ISO file is good and the burning as well.

Comment: I used windows tool to burn iso file, should I use other?

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Comment: Thats how I did it, I guess its drive issue. seems like nothing can be done with this drive?

Comment: Does the computer boot without the Ubuntu DVD inserted? If so, I'd suspect a bad DVD burn on Windows. Cheers, Al